# How to abort core-ajax in Polymer

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

say I have a `core-ajax` element configured as such:

```
<core-ajax url='/api/endpoint' response='{{handler}}'></core-ajax>
```

say I happen to hit the API at a higher frequency than inverse response time.

How do I ensure that `handler` only gets triggered by the last call to the api, regardless of return order? Basically when I make a new call I want to ignore all previous calls that haven't returned yet.

Comment: could be somewhat related to [this issue](https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/issues/12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with `job()` to push off work:

this.responseChanged = function() {
  this.job('job1', function() { // first arg is the name of the "job"
    ...
  }, 100); // delay callback 100ms. If `responseChanged()` is called again, it'll be another 100ms later...etc.
}

Docs: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#job

> You can call it repeatedly before the timeout but it only results in a single side-effect. In other words, if `responseChanged()` is immediately executed 250ms later, its callback won't be executed until 750ms.